# Update a field by taking user input only if it exists in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I have a collection of name, address, email and IsActive is default true for all collections.
I want change IsActive to false by taking user input.

User will give email address if it exists in collection then IsActive of that email address should be changed to false and if it does not exists an output should come as email address does not exist. collections are stored in collection file called user.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e155d4df9f62e4709a814b8"),
    "name" : "oihjoi",
    "Address" : "pojpjo",
    "Email" : "oiwjxoni@psdcmpd.com",
    "IsActive" : "True"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

def terminating_user_active():

```
result = user.update_one(
    {"Email": input("Enter email address to be terminated : ")}, {"$set": {"IsActive": False}})


if result.modified_count == 0:
    print("\n Entered email address does not exist in collection \n")

else:
    print("\n Entered email address active is terminated \n")
```

terminating_user_active()